# Top Bar on Collection View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

In my app, I have a collection view controller that is accessible by a modal type segue. What I am want is to have a top bar on the collection view controller. However, when I set a top bar in  attributes tab of the collection view controller, it shows on the storyboard but not in simulator?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that What you are looking for is a UICollectionReusableView.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UINavigationController.

If you're not using it, you could also add a UIToolbar.

That Storyboard section only sets the appearance in case you're using UINavigationController.